# Merging two rows of data

Tags: mysql

I have the following SQL Query..
It selects users that belong to multiple groups.
Each group has different or possibly the same permissions to programs.

```
SELECT app_name, priv_access, priv_insert, priv_delete, priv_update, priv_export, priv_print 
FROM news_sec_groups_apps 
WHERE group_id IN (SELECT group_id 
                   FROM news_sec_users_groups 
                   WHERE login = 'test2')
```

What I am trying to accomplish is creating an array that contains one row, showing the maximum value for each groups access.
For example if a group has access to priv_access and priv_export, and the other group has access to priv_delete.
I want to have a single record with the app_name, priv_access, priv_delete and priv_export all showing Y and the other items being null or No.

```
'form_imsi_news', 'Y', '', '', '', 'Y', ''
'form_imsi_news', NULL, NULL, Y, NULL, NULL, NULL
```

Should come out like this: 'form_imsi_news', 'Y', '', 'Y', '', 'Y', ''

Please any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to group your results by `app_name`:

```
SELECT app_name, max(priv_access), max(priv_insert), max(priv_delete),
       max(priv_update), max(priv_export), max(priv_print)
FROM news_sec_groups_apps 
WHERE group_id IN (SELECT group_id 
                   FROM news_sec_users_groups 
                   WHERE login = 'test2')
group by app_name
```

I think this will work directly because 'Y' > 'N' > '' and NULLs are ignored.